# How to sum up time field in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a column called "WrkHrs" and the data type is time(hh:mm:ss). I want to sum up the working hours for employees. But since it's time data type sql server doesn't let me use like `sum(columnname)`.

How can I sum up the time data type fieled in sql query?

Comment: And why are you using `TIME` for this instead of `INT` or `NUMERIC`?. Since the data is `TIME`, what should your query return when the work hours that you are aggregating are bigger than 24?, should the result be an `INT`?

Comment: @Lamak Yes I think I might as well use numeric data type. That would be easier for me to.

Comment: @AaronBertrand it's one column

Comment: I know it is one column. I'm questioning whether it should be.

Comment: Actually I have coulmns "start" and end. since I had been confused with how to calculate timediff, I created another column as hrs and let the user to enter it manually. so that I can easily sum up the hrs column. But now you gave me a good clue, I gonna try doing it in code.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
SELECT EmployeeID, minutes_worked = SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '0:00:00', WrkHrs)) 
FROM dbo.table 
-- WHERE ...
GROUP BY EmployeeID;
```

You can format it pretty on the front end. Or in T-SQL:

```
;WITH w(e, mw) AS
(
    SELECT EmployeeID, SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '0:00:00', WrkHrs)) 
    FROM dbo.table 
    -- WHERE ...
    GROUP BY EmployeeID
)
SELECT EmployeeID = e,
  WrkHrs = RTRIM(mw/60) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(mw%60),2)
  FROM w;
```

However, you're using the wrong data type. `TIME` is used to indicate a point in time, not an interval or duration. Wouldn't it make sense to store their work hours in two distinct columns, `StartTime` and `EndTime`?

Comment: I tried two columns, but the problem was timediff function calculates either diff between hours or minutes, but not together. I couldn't find a way to calculate hour and minutes together. That's why I choose this way.

Comment: IMHO this is not a problem. You can always get hours/minutes from minutes. 230 minutes = 2 hours 50 minutes. I demonstrate exactly this in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

In order to sum up the working hours for an employee you can calculate the difference between the shift start time and end time in minutes and convert it to readable format as following:

```
    DECLARE @StartTime      datetime = '08:00'
    DECLARE @EndTime        datetime = '10:47'
    DECLARE @durMinutes     int
    DECLARE @duration       nvarchar(5)

    SET @durMinutes = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @StartTime, @EndTime)

    SET @duration = 
    (SELECT RIGHT('00' + CAST((@durMinutes / 60) AS VARCHAR(2)),2) + ':' + 
            RIGHT('00' + CAST((@durMinutes % 60) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2))

    SELECT @duration
```

The result : **02:47**
two hours and 47 minutes

Answer (score 4):

```
select DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '0:00:00', '00:02:08')
```

results in :- 2

```
select DATEDIFF(SECOND, '0:00:00', '00:02:08')
```

results in :- 128

Using seconds gives a better answer.

So I think the answer can be

```
SELECT
    EmployeeId
    , seconds_worked = SUM (DATEDIFF (SECOND, '0:00:00', WrkHrs))
FROM
    tbl_employee
GROUP BY
    EmployeeId;
```

Comment: That doesn't address the summation part of the question. There's only one time column mentioned in the question but using `datediff` involves two values.

Comment: Updated answer, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: DATEDIFF expects SECOND, not SECONDS

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @Tab TABLE
(
    data CHAR(5)
)

INSERT @Tab
SELECT '25:30' UNION ALL
SELECT '31:45' UNION ALL
SELECT '16:00'

SELECT STUFF(CONVERT(CHAR(8), DATEADD(SECOND, theHours + theMinutes, 
    '19000101'), 8), 1, 2, CAST((theHours + theMinutes) / 3600 AS VARCHAR(12)))
FROM (
    SELECT ABS(SUM(CASE CHARINDEX(':', data) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 3600 * 
        LEFT(data, CHARINDEX(':', data) - 1) END)) AS theHours,
    ABS(SUM(CASE CHARINDEX(':', data) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 60 * 
        SUBSTRING(data, CHARINDEX(':', data) + 1, 2) END)) AS theMinutes
    FROM @Tab
) AS d
```

Answer (score 2):

For MS SQL Server, when your WorkingTime is stored as a time, or a varchar in order to sum it up you should consider that:

1) Time format is not supporting sum, so you need to parse it

2) 23:59:59.9999999 is the maximum value for the time.

So, the code that will work to get you the total number of WorkingHours:WorkingMinutes:WorkingSeconds would be the following:

```
SELECT 
 CAST(FORMAT((SUM((DATEPART("ss",WorkingTime) + DATEPART("mi",WorkingTime) * 60 + DATEPART("hh",WorkingTime) * 3600)) / 3600),'00') as varchar(max)) + ':' + 
  CAST(FORMAT((SUM((DATEPART("ss",WorkingTime) + DATEPART("mi",WorkingTime) * 60 + DATEPART("hh",WorkingTime) * 3600)) % 3600 / 60),'00') as varchar(max)) + ':' + 
  CAST(FORMAT((SUM((DATEPART("ss",WorkingTime) + DATEPART("mi",WorkingTime) * 60 + DATEPART("hh",WorkingTime) * 3600)) % 3600 % 60),'00') as varchar(max)) as WorkingTimeSum
FROM TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

It must be as simple as that.

Steps

- convert time to seconds
- sum the RESULT
- convert the sum to time
  Eg:
  take a case you might want to sum the following time:

```
| present_hours   |
|-----------------|
| 00:01:20.000000 |
|-----------------|
| 00:01:13.000000 |
|-----------------|
| 00:01:45.000000 |
|-----------------|
| 00:01:03.000000 |
|-----------------|
| 00:01:10.000000 |
|-----------------|
| 00:00:56.000000 |
```

```sql
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(present_hours))) as total_present_hours FROM time_booking;
```