# How to sum time spans stored in a varchar column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table In MS SQL-Server which has hours in a `varchar` column. For ex. `'4:30'` (hr:Min).  Basically it is a time span for an amount of work. Now I need the total sum of this column. How to convert it ?

My table looks like this

```
Create table tblWrkingHors
(
    Id int primary key,
    name varchar(50),
    WorkingHr varchar(8)
)
```

My table data is like this

```
==============================================================
Id       name       WorkingHr 
1        sam         08:20
2        sam         04:50
3        sam         04:34
4        Pam         05:50
5        sam         04:30
6        Pam         06:40
7        Pam         04:50
8       Todd         06:10
9       Todd         05:50
10      Todd         08:50
```

Comment: I'd recommend a one-time cleanup of your data and actually store the data numerically (maybe `NumMinutes int`) to make this easy to work with. Then create a function to convert the number of minutes to the readable format, and use that when you need it.

Comment: WorkingHr should be time

Comment: Since it's SQL Server, you could take @JoeEnos's suggestion one step further and define computed columns for hours and minutes, with the true data of record being stored in seconds.

Comment: Possible duplicate of  [How To sum up time field in sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725732/how-to-sum-up-time-field-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A VARCHAR may not be the most efficient version of storing time, but with a bit of casting you can do what you're looking for;

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT name, SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '00:00', CAST(WorkingHr AS TIME))) t
  FROM mytable GROUP BY name
)
SELECT name, RTRIM(t/60) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(t%60), 2) FROM cte
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/82ba8/1).

What it basically does is to cast the string to a TIME, then using DATEDIFF to convert the time to minutes. It then just basically sums up the minutes per name.

The outer query just converts minutes to a HH:MM string using simple string operations.

If you're not looking to group by name, the query can be simplified to;

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '00:00', CAST(WorkingHr AS TIME))) t FROM mytable
)
SELECT RTRIM(t/60) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(t%60), 2) FROM cte;
```

...which is pretty much the same query without grouping.

Comment: `DATEDIFF` FROM `00:00`, clever.  I would have never thought of that.  I would suggest re-storing this in the base table as seconds (in integer format), which would be much more efficient to sum.  But if this is a one-time thing, it makes sense to just parse it like you did.

Comment: Thanks to all who answered and also those who tried for this . I am very new in sql server and c# programming and with your help and suggestion will make me more efficient and accurate to take right decision while creating tables and select coulmn datatypes in future. and I wll tried to same on current project. thanks to everybody and yes sorry for my grammatical mistakes in comments

Comment: Hi tried the same but getting error:   1 errors were found during analysis.

    Unrecognized statement type. (near "WITH" at position 0)

Comment: @NarendraVyas Sounds like a MySQL error message, not an SQL Server one. Are you really using SQL Server as the question indicates?

Answer (score 2):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2ec56/2)

**MS SQL Server 2012 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Test_Table(Id INT, name VARCHAR(10), WorkingHr VARCHAR(8))
INSERT INTO Test_Table VALUES
(1        ,'sam' ,'08:20'),
(2        ,'sam' ,'04:50'),
(3        ,'sam' ,'04:34'),
(4        ,'Pam' ,'05:50'),
(5        ,'sam' ,'04:30'),
(6        ,'Pam' ,'06:40'),
(7        ,'Pam' ,'04:50'),
(8       ,'Todd' ,'06:10'),
(9       ,'Todd' ,'05:50'),
(10      ,'Todd' ,'08:50')
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT name
      ,CAST(DATEADD(MILLISECOND, 
               SUM(DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, '00:00:00.000'
         , CAST(WorkingHr AS TIME))), '00:00:00.000') AS TIME) AS Total_Time
FROM Test_Table
GROUP BY name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2ec56/2/0)**:

```
| NAME |       TOTAL_TIME |
|------|------------------|
|  Pam | 17:20:00.0000000 |
|  sam | 22:14:00.0000000 |
| Todd | 20:50:00.0000000 |
```

Comment: hello sir you gave very simplest answer to me thanks.but i tried you to vote up but was unable.sorry for that hope you don't mind

Answer (score 1):

Convert the times to a number of minutes before summing

```
SELECT
   SUM( 60 * CONVERT(int, LEFT( WorkingHr, 2)) +
             CONVERT(int, RIGHT(WorkingHr, 2))   ) AS TotalMinutes
FROM tblWorkingHours;
```

Or if you need the sum per person:

```
SELECT
   name,
   SUM( 60 * CONVERT(int, LEFT( WorkingHr, 2)) +
             CONVERT(int, RIGHT(WorkingHr, 2))   ) AS TotalMinutes
FROM tblWorkingHours
GROUP BY name;
```

However a `varchar` data type is probably not the best option. Store the time spans in minutes as `int`. It's the applications (front-end) responsibility to convert and display the data in an appropriate format, not the database's responsibility. Therefore choose a data type best suited for calculations, not for display.