# sum of multiple date columns from a single table in sql server? eg: select date1 + date2 from a table

Tags: sql-server

sum of multiple date columns from a single table in sql server? eg:

```
select date1 + date2 
from a table
```

I want to sum 2 columns consist of date like sum(date_1 + date_2)

Comment: What is the interpretation of that? Sum doesn't have sense. For example `date1 - date2 can be timespan` but sum??? Give result form `2015-01-01` + `2015-01-20`

Comment: Can you show an example of two dates and the result you expect when "adding" them?

Comment: SORRY!!! My apologize....is that possible to add time. like 11:23:34 + 12:22:34 and the result is 23:46:08. Any formula possibilities?

Comment: It's a bit complicated. There are three different answers to a similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725732/how-to-sum-up-time-field-in-sql-server.

Comment: If this question is about times, not dates then ... it still doesn't make sense in SQL Server. SQL Server has a `time` data type, but that represents a time of day, not a time *span*. So, again, adding such items together doesn't make sense. If this has to be done on the server, a better starting point would be to use an appropriate data type for storing time spans, which is unfortunately going to be e.g. `int` for just a pure count of the number of seconds. Of course, once you've got the correct type, summing them then becomes trivial.

Answer (score 0):

SUM their DATEDIFFs from some arbitrary point:

```
SELECT DATEADD(second, (DATEDIFF(second, 0, [Date1]) + DATEDIFF(second, 0, [Date2])), 0)
```