# Dynamic pivot with time datatype in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, sql-function

```
SELECT 
    PARTNO, BATCHNO, ' +   @IdleHoursColumns + '                              
INTO 
    TEMPTABLE_IH                            
FROM 
    [dbo].[PRODUCTION_IH]                               
PIVOT
    (SUM(IDLETIME))                              
          FOR REASON IN (' + @IdleHoursColumns + ')) AS P' 

--printed query 
SELECT 
    PARTNO, BATCHNO, [POWERCUT]                              
INTO 
    TEMPTABLE_IH                            
FROM 
    [dbo].[PRODUCTION_IH]                               
PIVOT
    (SUM(IDLETIME)                     
          FOR REASON IN ([POWERCUT])) AS P
```

How to use dynamic pivot with `time` datatype in SQL Server? I tried to move my data into a temp table and display the row values to as columns dynamically. The query works perfectly for integer datatype columns. But I got an error

> Operand data type time is invalid for sum operator

I tried with cast function and Datediff but it is also throwing errors.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725732/how-to-sum-up-time-field-in-sql-server) thread. You cannot sum up time, how do you expect "16:30" to sum up with "17:10"? What would be your expected result?

Answer (score 0):

If your datatype is not numeric then you should use  `MAX` or `MIN` instead of `SUM`

```
SELECT PARTNO,BATCHNO, ' +   @IdleHoursColumns + '                              
INTO TEMPTABLE_IH                            
FROM [dbo].[PRODUCTION_IH]                               
PIVOT( MAX(IDLETIME))                              
      FOR REASON IN (' + @IdleHoursColumns + ')) AS P'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
SELECT T1.PARTNO, T1.BATCHNO, T2.[POWERCUT] FROM (
SELECT PARTNO,BATCHNO,[POWERCUT]                              
    --INTO TEMPTABLE_IH                            
    FROM [DBO].[PRODUCTION_IH]                               
    PIVOT(MAX(IDLETIME)
          FOR REASON IN ([POWERCUT])) AS P)T1
    JOIN
    (
    SELECT PARTNO,BATCHNO, SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, IDLETIME)) / 60.0 AS [POWERCUT]
    FROM [DBO].[PRODUCTION_IH] 
    GROUP BY PARTNO,BATCHNO
    ) T2
ON T1.PARTNO = T2.PARTNO AND T1.BATCHNO = T2.BATCHNO
```

It will give you total time in hours. You can modify it to include all "Reason" columns.

HTH

Thanks.