# Calculate hours spent in office

Tags: sql-server

I have this table structure and some sample data in it. I want to calculate the number of total hours spent by each employee in office at the end of the month but when I run the following query I am getting this error.
Hope someone can help.

```
CREATE TABLE HOURSSPENT
(
EmpCode INT,
Time_Spent Time(5),
DayDate date
)

INSERT INTO HOURSSPENT VALUES (23, '08:30', '2018-07-12');
INSERT INTO HOURSSPENT VALUES (23, '05:40', '2018-07-13');
INSERT INTO HOURSSPENT VALUES (23, '07:23', '2018-07-16');
INSERT INTO HOURSSPENT VALUES (19, '08:30', '2018-07-12');
INSERT INTO HOURSSPENT VALUES (19, '05:40', '2018-07-13');
INSERT INTO HOURSSPENT VALUES (29, '07:23', '2018-07-12');


SELECT SUM(Time_Spent)
FROM HOURSSPENT
GROUP BY EmpCode
```

Error:

```
Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Operand data type time is invalid for sum operator.
```

Comment: `Time` is really intended to hold a time value, not a *timespan* value. You can use an integer to represent number of minutes, or use a checkin/checkout calculation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sum up time field in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725732/how-to-sum-up-time-field-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE HOURSSPENT
(
EmpCode INT,
Time_Spent Time(5),
DayDate date
)

INSERT INTO HOURSSPENT VALUES (23, '08:30', '2018-07-12');
INSERT INTO HOURSSPENT VALUES (23, '05:40', '2018-07-13');
INSERT INTO HOURSSPENT VALUES (23, '07:23', '2018-07-16');
INSERT INTO HOURSSPENT VALUES (19, '08:30', '2018-07-12');
INSERT INTO HOURSSPENT VALUES (19, '05:40', '2018-07-13');
INSERT INTO HOURSSPENT VALUES (29, '07:23', '2018-07-12');



SELECT EMPCODE,CAST(DATEADD(MILLISECOND,SUM(DATEDIFF
(MILLISECOND,0,CAST(TIME_SPENT AS DATETIME))),0) AS TIME) [sum of hrs] FROM HOURSSPENT
GROUP BY EMPCODE
```

output

```
EMPCODE sum of hrs
19      14:10:00.0000000
23      21:33:00.0000000
29      07:23:00.0000000
```

Comment: This will give the wrong result if the accumulated time > 24 hours. Try set the hour part of `Time_Spent` for `EmpCode = 23` to `8` for all records. `Time` is really the wrong datatype for this sort of data.

Comment: `Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.`

Comment: @HoneyBadger Which datatype should I use ?

Comment: @DoonieDarkoo, it depends on how you use the data, and how you get the data. You can store time spent as integer in minutes. A better way might be to use a check-in and a check-out column (both in `datetime2`), and use `datediff` on those. (One) advantage of the last method is you can drop the `DayDate` column. Either way, you'd still have to do some trickery to *present* the value as `HH:MM:SS`; the usual place for this is presentation layer, not data layer, though.

Comment: @HoneyBadger I have CheckIn and CheckOut and that's how I'm getting total hours spent in a day but I want to calculate total hours spent in month as well. 
I'm not sure how to figure this out. But thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0):

use `DATEDIFF()` to get the difference in minute and then SUM it up. Divide by 60 to convert back to hour

```
SELECT  EmpCode, SUM(datediff(minute, 0, Time_Spent)) / 60.0
FROM    HOURSSPENT
GROUP BY EmpCode

If the total time will not exceed 24 hours, you can just simply do this

SELECT  EmpCode, 
        convert(time, dateadd(minute, SUM(datediff(minute, 0, Time_Spent)), 0))
FROM    HOURSSPENT
GROUP BY EmpCode

else, you need to calculate the day, hour, minute separately

day = Total_spent / 60 / 60
```

Comment: But here the minute part won't come out right. It will be `14.166666` instead of `14:10:00.0000000`

Comment: not a issue. I will update the query, anyway that is just formatting issue

Comment: @Squirrel Please update query and keep in mind that time will increase 24 hours and make it in time format

Comment: `TIME` data type cannot accept more than 24 hours. You should keep the total time spend in either minutes or hours (depends on your requirement) and let your front end application format it in the way you want