# How can I add and group items in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am producing the following query and would like to group the records by the `CODHORESC` column and sum the `HOURS` column.

For example, I have this data:

```
 14  Quarta-Feira   HORÁRIO DIURNO       8:00:00  
 14  Quarta-Feira   HORÁRIO DIURNO       2:00:00
```

They would like it to look like this:

```
 14  Quarta-Feira   HORÁRIO DIURNO       10:00:00
```

This is my SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    DATENAME(dw, DATA) DIASEM, 
    HORARIOS.DESCRICAO CODHOR, 
    IIF(DATEDIFF(HOUR, HORINI, HORFIM) >= 0, CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), DATEDIFF(second, HORINI, HORFIM) / 3600) + ':' 
+ RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), (DATEDIFF(second, HORINI, HORFIM) % 
3600) / 60), 2) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEDIFF(second, 
HORINI, HORFIM) % 60), 2), CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), datediff(second, HORINI, DATEADD(DAY, 1, HORFIM))/3600) + ':' 
+ RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), (DATEDIFF(second, HORINI, DATEADD(DAY, 1, HORFIM)) % 
3600) / 60), 2) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEDIFF(second, 
HORINI, DATEADD(DAY, 1, HORFIM)) % 60), 2)) HORAS
FROM 
    HORESC
INNER JOIN 
    HORARIOS ON HORARIOS.CODHOR = HORESC.CODHOR
INNER JOIN 
    HORAS ON HORARIOS.CODHOR = HORAS.CODHOR
```

Result obtained:

```
CODHORESC  DIASEM         CODHOR               HORAS    
---------  -------------  -------------------  -------  
        1  Segunda-Feira  HORÁRIO MATINAL      8:00:00  
        2  Terça-Feira    HORÁRIO MATINAL      8:00:00  
        3  Quinta-Feira   HORÁRIO DIURNO       8:00:00  
        3  Quinta-Feira   HORÁRIO DIURNO       2:00:00  
        4  Sexta-Feira    HORÁRIO DIURNO       8:00:00  
        4  Sexta-Feira    HORÁRIO DIURNO       2:00:00  
        5  Sábado         HORÁRIO DIURNO       8:00:00  
        5  Sábado         HORÁRIO DIURNO       2:00:00  
        6  Domingo        DESCANSO REMUNERADO  0:00:00  
        7  Segunda-Feira  HORÁRIO NOTURNO      8:00:00  
        8  Terça-Feira    HORÁRIO NOTURNO      8:00:00  
        9  Quarta-Feira   HORÁRIO NOTURNO      8:00:00  
       10  Quinta-Feira   HORÁRIO NOTURNO      8:00:00  
       11  Sexta-Feira    HORÁRIO NOTURNO      8:00:00  
       12  Sábado         HORÁRIO NOTURNO      8:00:00  
       13  Domingo        DESCANSO REMUNERADO  0:00:00  
       14  Quarta-Feira   HORÁRIO DIURNO       8:00:00  
       14  Quarta-Feira   HORÁRIO DIURNO       2:00:00  
       15  Quinta-Feira   HORÁRIO DIURNO       8:00:00  
       15  Quinta-Feira   HORÁRIO DIURNO       2:00:00  
       16  Sexta-Feira    HORÁRIO DIURNO       8:00:00  
       16  Sexta-Feira    HORÁRIO DIURNO       2:00:00  
       17  Sábado         DESCANSO REMUNERADO  0:00:00  
       18  Quarta-Feira   HORÁRIO MATINAL      8:00:00  
       19  Quinta-Feira   HORÁRIO MATINAL      8:00:00  
       20  Sexta-Feira    HORÁRIO MATINAL      8:00:00  
       21  Domingo        DESCANSO REMUNERADO  0:00:00  
       22  Segunda-Feira  HORÁRIO DIURNO       8:00:00  
       22  Segunda-Feira  HORÁRIO DIURNO       2:00:00  
       23  Terça-Feira    HORÁRIO DIURNO       8:00:00  
       23  Terça-Feira    HORÁRIO DIURNO       2:00:00  
       24  Sábado         HORÁRIO MATINAL      8:00:00  
       25  Domingo        DESCANSO REMUNERADO  0:00:00  
       26  Segunda-Feira  HORÁRIO DIURNO       8:00:00  
       26  Segunda-Feira  HORÁRIO DIURNO       2:00:00  
       27  Terça-Feira    HORÁRIO DIURNO       8:00:00  
       27  Terça-Feira    HORÁRIO DIURNO       2:00:00
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could `GROUP BY` CODHORESC  and `SUM(HORAS)` after you are done with all your conversions.

Here is an example : [SQL SUM() function with group by](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/sum-with-group-by.php)

In order to sum `time` you will need to do some more changes to your query : [How to sum up time field in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725732/how-to-sum-up-time-field-in-sql-server)

Comment: You can't `SUM` a `time` (or `varchar`).

Answer (score 0):

will this work?

```
select CODHORESC, Max(DIASEM) DIASEM, Max(CODHOR) CODHOR,sum(datediff(minute, 0, HORAS)) / 60.0 HORAS from tblSuperTable group by CODHORESC
```